# Android:Error:(20, 51) error: cannot find symbol variable Message_Text

Tags: android

I am trying to send data through an activity to another but there is a variable error that I didn't understand, please Help. Thank you very much for your time and assistance in this matter.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
  EditText Message_Text;
  public final  static String MESSAGE_KEY="com.example.zeeshan.userinterface.message_key";

  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
  }

  public void sendMessage(View views) {
    Message_Text= (EditText) findViewById(R.id.Message_Text);

    String message=Message_Text.getText().toString();
    Intent intent= new Intent(this, SecondActivity.class);
    intent.putExtra(MESSAGE_KEY,message);
    startActivity(intent);
  }
}
```

the second activity code is:

```
public class SecondActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
  public final  static String MESSAGE_KEY="com.example.zeeshan.userinterface.message_key";

  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    Intent intent= getIntent();
    String message = intent.getStringExtra(MESSAGE_KEY);
    TextView textView = new TextView(this);
    textView.setTextSize(35);
    // setContentView(R.layout.second_layout);
  }
}
```

Comment: Post your activity_main.xml

Comment: It's probably an error in your xml layout. Is there a `Message_Text`?

Answer (score 0):

you have to write like below.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    sendMessage();
}

public void sendMessage() {
        EditText Message_Text= (EditText) findViewById(R.id.Message_Text);

        String message=Message_Text.getText().toString();
        Intent intent= new Intent(this, SecondActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra("MESSAGE_KEY",message);
        startActivity(intent);


    }
```

Comment: my error is just in one variable when i initialize the edit text using findViewById(R.id.Message_Text) the Message_Text variable show error

Comment: can you please share your activity_main.xml